# create redirect link/post to woocommerce payment page with pending status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Halo everyone, hope you always health.
how i can make every user who visit a link/post will redirect to woocommerce customer payment page for newest order with pending status.

here the code to call customer payment page url

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$pay_now_url = esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() );
echo $pay_now_url; //http://example.com/checkout/order-pay/{order_id}?pay_for_order=true&key={order_key}
```

i want www.myweb,com/lucky-buy redirect to every NEWEST wc order payment page with order status pending payment. so every time i create order on wc backend with status pending payment, user can pay that order by visiting www.myweb,com/lucky-buy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? You pasted a bit of code, but no explanation. Also, tagging something as **urgent** will most likely get this down voted: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it.

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bks_redirect_to_pay_latest_pending_order');

function bks_redirect_to_pay_latest_pending_order(){
    // Check if its lucky-buy page and user is logged in
    if(is_page('lucky-buy') && is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Get latest customer order with status as mentioned
        $query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
            'limit'    => 1,
            'orderby'  => 'date',
            'order'    => 'DESC',
            'return'   => 'ids',
            'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
            'status'   => array('wc-pending'),
        ) );
        $orders = $query->get_orders();
         // check order is not empty
        if (!empty($orders)) {
            $order = wc_get_order($orders[0]);
            $url = $order->get_checkout_payment_url();
            // redirect
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit ;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added comment for better understanding. Add status as and when needed.

> References
>
> - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#table-of-contents
> - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/